# What's wrong with a question about C/OS interaction?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Using stackoverflow has become a run against time: will I get an answer to my question before five close votes are in?

My latest question [How to feed contents of a "shebang" file into the program it invokes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523857/how-to-let-a-c-c-program-read-from-a-shebang-file) was about interaction between a C or C++ program and the operating system. Within minutes, I got two answers. Each of them fully answered my question, and thereby helped me enormously in my work.

Since then my question received four 'close' votes without any further explanation. All votes were of category 'off topic' ('does not appear to be about programming'), subcategory 'Questions seeking debugging help'.

I'd say, something is broken in the social mechanism when questions get closed because a few people understand them wrongly.

To me it seems perfectly clear that my question was about 'programming', but not about 'debugging'. My question was basically: How do I feed information from process A into process B. Then I elaborated: Currently, B reads from stdin; this seems to be the wrong approach; how shall I proceed instead.

The 'debugging' close-reason category says: 'must include ... the shortest code necessary to reproduce ...'. With my question, it would have been ridiculous to submit sample code of B when all was said with 'reads from stdin'. Which shows how inadequate the close reason was.

Comment: Wow - one close vote less! My respect to the anonymous colleague who corrected himself.

Comment: it could be that first voter or flagger misread the question, picked wrong reason and then the rest just followed the lead. [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773) is a known issue, so far it only didn't pop up frequently enough to warrant system changes (guess it's not always easy to get four 3K users to do things wrong)

Comment: That's my close vote retracted, now I understood your question. I rephrased it a bit (mostly moving things around) to make your actual problem more apparent. I'd read your question about 3-4 times before, and understood just now. Is the update ok? (Rollback otherwise. I'll clean up comments here, sorry for the noise.)

Comment: Please read the whole close reason: "Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers**." (emphasis mine). Your problem statement wasn't clear, as was your _specific_ problem (which was misunderstanding the shebang mechanism, not reading that file). And you specifically asked "how to modify foo" without showing foo, that's akin to asking for this close reason.

Comment: @Mat: Thank you very much for the edit. I think I understand what was unclear in my question.

Comment: Your subsequent edit muddies the water. The fact that you want to "go interactive" after reading the script is a secondary matter if you can't read the script in the first place. Makes your actual (current) issue less clear IMO. Would be a followup question is you can't get the "go interactive" part to work after having managed to process the file.

Comment: Simple.  Stay away from C++.

Comment: Also, re your shebang question... you put forward your requirements, and expect others to do your work for you.  That's kinda rude.  We expect you to TRY and do something first, then if you get stuck ask a question.  Your question contains no code, nor any indication that you have attempted to create your code prior to asking.  Think of SO as the ***last resort***, not the first.

Comment: My question contained no code because it was not about _how_ to code but about _what_ to code. Whether in C++ or C doesn't matter at all. Sorry, Will, your comments are not helpful. Maybe you should ask the two colleagues who so nicely answered my original question whether they considered it rude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that anyone answered does not in and of itself mean that the question *should have been answered* (at least in its current state), or that it *should **not** be closed*.
At most, it *might* mean that someone could divine your meaning (or felt lucky), in which case he should edit it into shape.

That has exactly nothing to do with harassment.

Having said that, I don't see how your question is in need of closing, anyway.

Comment: I took harassment out, though personally I find it hard not to _feel_ harassed when I receive anonymous negative judgement without adequate explanation.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke: While improper closing is slightly annoying, fast closing is the right thing, shutting down crap content. The first edit by the author, as well as any re-open vote, will push it into the always empty re-open queue, which will lead to a fast resolution.